# How to append image to div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to append an image to div with jQuery, this is my code:

```
$img = '<img src="my-correct-link.png" />';
$js =  '<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(".wonderpluginslider").append(' . $img .');
            });
        </script>';
echo $js;
```

The image not appears, if I replace the value of $img with simple `$img = 'hello';`, hello is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Did you do an inspect to see if the image tag is in the code or not?

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as your PHP document? You need to provide a valid relative or absolute URL as the `src` attribute.

Comment: is the path right? You say you see no image but the tag is there isn't it?

Comment: There isn't img tag, yes the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have quotes around your image HTML, the call to append requires a string, you should be getting a JavaScript syntax error.

Your HTML output now looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".wonderpluginslider").append(<img src="my-correct-link.png" />);
});
</script>;
```

But needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".wonderpluginslider").append('<img src="my-correct-link.png" />');
});
</script>;
```

The safest way is to use [json_encocde](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$img = '<img src="my-correct-link.png" />';
$js =  '<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(".wonderpluginslider").append(' . json_encode($img).');
            });
        </script>';
echo $js;
```